# Crop CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, core-image, firebase-mlkit

I'm using Firebase ML Kit to recognise text that's visible within a small window. But I want to make it more efficient, helping it to not analyse unnecessary data. So I would like to crop the image being sent to the model.

Firebase ML is taking a `VisionImage` which takes a `CMSampleBuffer`.
The only part of the image I would need is the same width, but is only about 100px high, like the blue part here:

[image: Image showing the used part of the image captured]

I haven't found a good way to do this yet, or is it better to take the image from the preview that is shown to the user and then convert it back?

I'm thinking that this should be done inside the `captureOutput` function from the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. My function looks like this today:

```
func captureOutput(
    _ output: AVCaptureOutput,
    didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
    from connection: AVCaptureConnection
    ) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updatePreviewOverlayView()
    }

    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    self.lastFrame = sampleBuffer
    let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
    let metadata = VisionImageMetadata()
    let visionOrientation = VisionDetectorImageOrientation.rightTop
    metadata.orientation = visionOrientation
    visionImage.metadata = metadata
    let imageWidth = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer))
    let imageHeight = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
    self.recognizeTextOnDevice(in: visionImage, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the same thing. I wish you could just pass a rect to Firebase ML Kit. So far it seems like we have to convert to a CGImage and resize. Let me know if you've found a solution though

Comment: Did you guys find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately... no.